# Flash, JSON and special chars, how read òàùèéì on flash with JSON?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, json, character-encoding, char

I've a problem loading a JSON with flash class com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON
It works fine with everything except I haven't found a way to load special chars, so if i have

```
{
    "json_text":"Hello, goodbye! I work fine!"
}
```

but If i need a special char like àùòèéì it won't work, I've tryied with

```
{
    "json_text":"òàùèéì I return nothing in my TextField"
}
```

But flash won't load this chars on my TextField object, so I'ev also tryied:

```
{
    "json_text":"&egrave;&agrave;&eacute etc. ERROR ERROR!!"
}
```

But it return the error by the adobe class... How can avoid the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the JSON you load is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: When I'll go to office will be my first task! thanks for suggestion

Comment: In fact, it was a php problem!

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark (I don't have access to Flash right now) but did you try setting the `Content-Type` header of the json page to: "application/json; **charset=ISO-8859-1**" ?

Comment: FlashPlayer could only handle utf8 encoding, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe special character must be escaped this way: `\uffa6\u1234` (`\u` + hexadecimal representation of the char.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it, but seems flash doesn't like it. It Simply doesn't return the special char like my second case